# Expectation of Epsilon squared MA(1)

Tags: statistics

For an MA(1) process can someone explain expanding the error term epsilon? $$var(Y_t) = E[(Y_t-\mu)^2]$$
Specifically why is the expectation of epsilon squared = $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ when the expectation of epsilon is 0?

Comment: If $X=+1$ or $-1$ each with probability $\frac12$, then  $E[X]=0$ but $E[X^2]=1$

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the [moving average process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) of order 1:
$$
      Y_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + b_1 \epsilon_{t-1}, \phantom{for} t \geqslant 0
$$
where $\epsilon_{t}$ for $t \geqslant -1$ are independent identically distributed centered Gaussian random variables with standard deviation $\sigma_\epsilon$, i.e
$$
    Y_0 = \mu + \epsilon_0 + b_1 \epsilon_{-1}, \phantom{and} Y_{1} =  \mu + \epsilon_{1} + b_1 \epsilon_{0}, \phantom{and} Y_{2} = \mu + \epsilon_{2} + b_1 \epsilon_{1}, \phantom{and} \dots
$$
Therefore:
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left(Y_t\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\mu + \epsilon_t + b_1 \epsilon_{t-1} \right) = \mu + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_t\right)}_{= 0} + b_1 \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_{t-1} \right)}_{=0} = \mu
$$
since $\epsilon_t$ are centered (zero mean) Gaussian variables.

Proceeding to OP's question:
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left( \left(Y_t - \mu\right)^2 \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \left(\epsilon_t + b_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}\right)^2 \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \epsilon_t^2 \right) + 2 b_1 \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_t \epsilon_{t-1}\right) 
+ b_1^2 \mathbb{E}\left( \epsilon_{t-1}^2 \right)
$$
Since $\epsilon_t$ are independent, $\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_t \epsilon_{t-1}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_t\right)\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_{t-1}\right) = 0$, and since they are identically distributed $\mathbb{E}\left( \epsilon_{t}^2 \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \epsilon_{t-1}^2 \right) = \mathbb{Var}\left(\epsilon_t\right) = \sigma_\epsilon^2$.

Hence:
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left( \left(Y_t - \mu\right)^2 \right) = \left(1 + b_1^2\right) \sigma_\epsilon^2
$$

Comment: Perfect. A very thorough explanation. What I think I was misunderstanding was the distribution of $\epsilon$. From what I gather your saying $\epsilon_t$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2_\epsilon)$ which is why we can make the assumption that the expectation of epsilon is 0 but since it's both squared and iid then $E[\epsilon_t^2] = \sigma^2_{\epsilon}$